# One large table or many small ones in database?

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design

Say I want to create a typical todo-webApp using a db like postgresql. A user should be able to create todo-lists. On this lists he should be able to make the actual todo-entries.

I regard the todo-list as an object which has different properties like owner, name, etc, and of course the actual todo-entries which have their own properties like content, priority, date ... .

My idea was to create a table for all the todo-lists of all the users. In this table I would store all the attributes of each list. But the questions which arises is how to store the todo-entries themselves? Of course in an additional table, but should I rather:

**1. Create one big table for all the entries** and have a field storing the id of the todo-list they belong to, like so:

```
todo-list: id, owner, ...
todo-entries: list.id, content, ...
```

which would give 2 tables in total. The todo-entries table could get very large. Although we know that entries expire, hence the table only grows with more usage but not over time. Then we would write something like `SELECT * FROM todo-entries WHERE todo-list-id=id` where `id` is the of the list we are trying to retrieve.

OR

**2. Create a todo-entries table on a per user basis**.

```
todo-list: id, owner, ...
todo-entries-owner: list.id, content,. ..
```

Number of entries table depends on number of users in the system. Something like `SELECT * FROM todo-entries-owner`. Mid-sized tables depending on the number of entries users do in total.

OR

**3. Create one todo-entries-table *for each* todo-list** and then store a generated table name in a field for the table. For instance could we use the todos-list unique id in the table name like:

```
todo-list: id, owner, entries-list-name, ...    
todo-entries-id: content, ... //the id part is the id from the todo-list id field.
```

In the third case we could potentially have quite a large number of tables. A user might create many 'short' todo-lists. To retrieve the list we would then simply go along the lines `SELECT * FROM todo-entries-id` where `todo-entries-id` should be either a field in the todo-list or it could be done implicitly by concatenating 'todo-entries' with the todos-list unique id.  Btw.: How do I do that, should this be done in `js` or can it be done in PostgreSQL directly? And very related to this: in the `SELECT * FROM <tablename>` statement, is it possible to have the value of some field of some other table as `<tablename>`? Like `SELECT * FROM todo-list(id).entries-list-name` or so.

The three possibilities go from few large to many small tables. My personal feeling is that the second or third solutions are better. I think they might scale better. But I'm not sure quite sure of that and I would like to know what the 'typical' approach is.

I could go more in depth of what I think of each of the approaches, but to get to the point of my question:

- Which of the three possibilities should I go for? (or anything else, has this to do with normalization?)

Follow up:

- What would the (PostgreSQL) statements then look like?

Comment: Table creation really shouldn't be something that's happening dynamically in the app. As soon as you start doing that, it's time to ask whether your design needs rethinking. So certainly option #1.  (Partitioning and sharding is a workaround for database system limitations, and while you might get there eventually, it's not something you should generally start with.)

Comment: Don't be afraid of more tables: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?FearOfAddingTables

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan: could you elaborate? Would you go as far as _recommending_ having dynamically created tables?

Comment: Don't create tables just because the clock is changing (tasks_2016) or adding users (tasks_frank). DO favour more, smaller tables over fewer, large tables for normalized design.

Comment: @CraigRinger: Hey! I completely believe you, but I would love to know why it is not good to create tables dynamically. What is the reasoning to see that this is an issue? Does it depend on the rate of how many tables we are creating and deleting or you think it's bad in general?

Comment: If you're dynamically creating tables then all your DDL lands up being in `DO` blocks that query `information_schema` to apply a change to a bunch of identical tables. Annoying. Querying aggregate data across all customers or whatever suddenly turns into the Union Query Of Doom. The proliferation of tables isn't great for dump/restore performance. It's harder to analyse query patterns with things like `pg_stat_statements`. Lots of reasons, but the biggest is that *there's no good reason to do it*.  Want to group data by customer? Composite PK. `PRIMARY KEY (customer_id, whatever_other_key)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only viable option is the first. It is far easier to manage and will very likely be faster than the other options.

Image you have 1 million users, with an average of 3 to-do lists each, with an average of 5 entries per list.

### Scenario 1

In the first scenario you have three tables:

- `todo_users`: 1 million records
- `todo_lists`: 3 million records
- `todo_entries`: 15 million records

Such table sizes are no problem for PostgreSQL and with the right indexes you will be able to retrieve any data in less than a second (meaning just simple queries; if your queries become more complex (like: get me the todo_entries for the longest todo_list of the top 15% of todo_users that have made less than 3 todo_lists in the 3-month period with the highest todo_entries entered) it will obviously be slower (as in the other scenarios). The queries are very straightforward:

```
-- Find user data based on username entered in the web site
-- An index on 'username' is essential here
SELECT * FROM todo_users WHERE username = ?;

-- Find to-do lists from a user whose userid has been retrieved with previous query
SELECT * FROM todo_lists WHERE userid = ?;

-- Find entries for a to-do list based on its todoid
SELECT * FROM todo_entries WHERE listid = ?;
```

You can also combine the three queries into one:

```
SELECT u.*, l.*, e.* -- or select appropriate columns from the three tables
FROM todo_users u
LEFT JOIN todo_lists l ON l.userid = u.id
LEFT JOIN todo_entries e ON e.listid = l.id
WHERE u.username = ?;
```

Use of the `LEFT JOIN`s means that you will also get data for users without lists or lists without entries (but column values will be `NULL`).

Inserting, updating and deleting records can be done with very similar statements and similarly fast.

PostgreSQL stores data on "pages" (typically 4kB in size) and most pages will be filled, which is a good thing because reading a writing a page are **very** slow compared to other operations.

### Scenario 2

In this scenario you need only two tables per user (`todo_lists` and `todo_entries`) but you need some mechanism to identify which tables to query.

- 1 million `todo_lists` tables with a few records each
- 1 million `todo_entries` tables with a few dozen records each

The only practical solution to that is to construct the full table names from a "basename" related to the username or some other persistent authentication data from your web site. So something like this:

```
username = 'Jerry';
todo_list = username + '_lists';
todo_entries = username + '_entries';
```

And then you query with those table names. More likely you will need a `todo_users` table anyway to store personal data, usernames and passwords of your 1 million users.

In most cases the tables will be very small and PostgreSQL will not use any indexes (nor does it have to). It will have more trouble finding the appropriate tables, though, and you will most likely build your queries in code and then feed them to PostgreSQL, meaning that it cannot optimize a query plan. A bigger problem is creating the tables for new users (todo_list and todo_entries) or deleting obsolete lists or users. This typically requires behind-the scenes housekeeping that you avoid with the previous scenario. And the biggest performance penalty will be that most pages have only little content so you waste disk space and **lots** of time reading and writing those partially filled pages.

### Scenario 3

This scenario is even worse that scenario 2. Don't do it, it's madness.

- 3 million tables `todo_entries` with a few records each

### So...

Stick with option 1. It is your only real option.

Comment: Ok. thanks a lot for your answer. My intuition in scenario 1 was that it is a bit strange, to have a field to tell to which list a todo-entry belongs to and then having to filter according to that field, although actually I could have directly a table of those entries. You see how all the users in the system query the same table to filter out their portion. It's kind of mixing the entries together to then separate them again when retrieving them. Funny, isn't it? The other thing is: is this answer domain specific? Assume you would know that todo-lisis are rly long, would your answer change?

Comment: I take the freedom to answer here :-) Database design has nothing to do with how many rows you expect in a table. A user is a user. It doesn't matter whether there are two users or two billion users in your database; the table will be the same. As soon as you create two tables with exactly the same columns in a database, your design is *probably bad*. As soon as you have data in your table names or column names (such as in a country table there is 'China' and then you have a table departments_in_china or a table product_sales with a column sold_in_china, your design is *definitely bad*.

Comment: @dingalapadum **Relational** database management systems are purposely built to support scenario 1 and there is a lot of optimization in linking data from different tables and filtering based on criteria (such as in `JOIN ON` and `WHERE` clauses). The answer is indeed domain-specific, namely to RDBMS's such as PostgreSQL. The neat thing is that it does not matter how large the to-do lists are, scenario 1 will always work, no matter how many users, lists or entries.

Comment: Ok. I guess my intuition is wrong then. I assume the reason for this is that creating tables & looking them up is rly expensive compared to looking up _in a_ table. In an OO design I would say there is a "has a" relation between lists & entries. Hence I would have an array of entries for each list. It feels odd to store all entries of all lists in a single array to then have to search for the keys to find the entries for a given list. Although, maybe with some optimized data-structure it makes sense. So, I'll accept the answer. What about NoSql, would there my proposed layout work?

Comment: I do not know enough of NOSQL to answer but your use case does not point in that direction. What I do know is that you should try out the above solution first: your problem fits very neatly within the PostgreSQL way of doing things and you will have very good performance. It is a no-brainer really.